# jquery .load, called from inside of loaded content

Tags: jquery, bind, jquery-load

im using .load to load content into a div, i would then like to load in new content called from inside the 1st loaded content ..

ive also got the a nivo slider running from inside the loaded content so at the moment its looking like this

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    $("#pegasus-tile, #o-w").click(function(){
        $("#proj-content").load("projects/pegasus.html", function(){
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"></div>      
            $('#slider').nivoSlider();
        });
    });
});
```

i beleve its should look like somthing like this ...

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    $("#pegasus-tile, #o-w").click(function(){
        $("#proj-content").load("projects/pegasus.html", function(){

            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"></div>
            $('#slider').nivoSlider(),

            $("#close").click(function(){
                $("#proj-content").load("projects/blank.html");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

...but i just cant get it too work, any helps much appreciated

Comment: It looks like you are mixing HTML with your Javascript.  What are you trying to accomplish with the nivoSlider div placed inside your load function?  Is this supposed to be appended to the end of your loaded content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a div to the page using jQuery, you want to do the following:

```
$('<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"></div>').appendTo($('body'));
```

Replacing `$('body')` with any selector or jQuery object where you waqnt the `div` added.

You cannot just put HTML inside of a javascript.  This might by fluke be ignored, depending on where you defined your javascript, but it isn't valid, and isn't doing what you think.

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    $("#pegasus-tile, #o-w").click(function(){
        $("#proj-content").load("projects/pegasus.html", function(){

            $('<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"></div>').appendTo('#proj-sontent');
            $('#slider').nivoSlider(),

            $("#close").click(function(){
                $("#proj-content").load("projects/blank.html");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: ahhhh, ok thanks very much for that jeff, somthing odd ive just found, it wont work if the site is hosted localy, but works fine once its on a server is that normal ?

Comment: Possibly due to cross-site scripting restrictions.